# How do I configure irssi?

Tags: configuration, irc, irssi

I am using the **irssi** client for IRC chat, and I would like to know how to configure the `~/.irssi/config` file so that I can put in my username and password (I have a registered nickname in the IRC).

Also, I'd like to know if I can configure it to open multiple terminals (as in gnome-terminal windows) to connect to different channels like *#ubuntu*, *#ubuntu-in*, etc. Or should I alias the command with different parameters so as to connect to different channels from different terminals?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Here is a [short note](https://gist.github.com/johnjohndoe/d8bbe1840e79b07ca1304ffb6606d14d) where to find the configuration file and how to run it when you install `irssi` via `snap` on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You've asked a lot of questions in one, but I'll help you with as many of them as I can.

First, you need to add your IRC server of choice - fire up irssi, and type the following:

`/server add -auto -network Freenode irc.freenode.net 6667`

That will add the Freenode IRC network to your IRSSI config, and will automatically connect when you run `irssi`.

`/network add -nick <your-nick> Freenode`

That will add your nick to the new `Freenode` network, and will automatically use that nick whenever connecting to the network.

`/channel add -auto #ubuntu Freenode`

That will make you join `#ubuntu` on Freenode everytime you run irssi.

Assuming you have your nick registered, you can do this to identify automatically:

`/network add -autosendcmd "/msg nickserv identify password ;wait 2000" Freenode`

You can switch between channels with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>3</kbd>, etc, with each channel being <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Number</kbd>

If you're interested, here is my `~/.irrsi/config` file:

```
servers = (
  { address = "irc.ubuntu.com"; chatnet = "Ubuntu"; port = "8001"; },
  #There is actually very little difference between irc.ubuntu.com
  # and irc.freenode.net - irc.u.c is just a redirect
  {
    address = "irc.freenode.net";
    chatnet = "Freenode";
    port = "6667";
    use_ssl = "no";
    ssl_verify = "no";
    autoconnect = "yes";
  }
);
# I'm a freenode user all the way man
chatnets = {
  Freenode = {
    type = "IRC";
    nick = "changeme";
    autosendcmd = "/msg nickserv identify <password removed> ;wait 2000";
  };
};

# Channels I hang out in a lot. Change these to your own.
channels = (
  { name = "#2buntu"; chatnet = "Freenode"; autojoin = "yes"; },
);

aliases = {
  J = "join";
  WJOIN = "join -window";
  WQUERY = "query -window";
  LEAVE = "part";
  BYE = "quit";
  EXIT = "quit";
  SIGNOFF = "quit";
  DESCRIBE = "action";
  DATE = "time";
  HOST = "userhost";
  LAST = "lastlog";
  SAY = "msg *";
  WI = "whois";
  WII = "whois $0 $0";
  WW = "whowas";
  W = "who";
  N = "names";
  M = "msg";
  T = "topic";
  C = "clear";
  CL = "clear";
  K = "kick";
  KB = "kickban";
  KN = "knockout";
  BANS = "ban";
  B = "ban";
  MUB = "unban *";
  UB = "unban";
  IG = "ignore";
  UNIG = "unignore";
  SB = "scrollback";
  UMODE = "mode $N";
  WC = "window close";
  WN = "window new hide";
  SV = "say Irssi $J ($V) - http://irssi.org/";
  GOTO = "sb goto";
  CHAT = "dcc chat";
  RUN = "SCRIPT LOAD";
  CALC = "exec - if command -v bc >/dev/null 2>&1\\; then printf '%s=' '$*'\\; echo '$*' | bc -l\\; else echo bc was not found\\; fi";
  SBAR = "STATUSBAR";
  INVITELIST = "mode $C +I";
  Q = "QUERY";
  "MANUAL-WINDOWS" = "set use_status_window off;set autocreate_windows off;set autocreate_query_level none;set autoclose_windows off;set reuse_unused_windows on;save";
  EXEMPTLIST = "mode $C +e";
  ATAG = "WINDOW SERVER";
  UNSET = "set -clear";
  RESET = "set -default";
};

statusbar = {
  # formats:
  # when using {templates}, the template is shown only if it's argument isn't
  # empty unless no argument is given. for example {sb} is printed always,
  # but {sb $T} is printed only if $T isn't empty.

  items = {
    # start/end text in statusbars
    barstart = "{sbstart}";
    barend = "{sbend}";

    topicbarstart = "{topicsbstart}";
    topicbarend = "{topicsbend}";

    # treated "normally", you could change the time/user name to whatever
    time = "{sb $Z}";
    user = "{sb {sbnickmode $cumode}$N{sbmode $usermode}{sbaway $A}}";

    # treated specially .. window is printed with non-empty windows,
    # window_empty is printed with empty windows
    window = "{sb $winref:$tag/$itemname{sbmode $M}}";
    window_empty = "{sb $winref{sbservertag $tag}}";
    prompt = "{prompt $[.15]itemname}";
    prompt_empty = "{prompt $winname}";
    topic = " $topic";
    topic_empty = " Irssi v$J - http://www.irssi.org";

    # all of these treated specially, they're only displayed when needed
    lag = "{sb Lag: $0-}";
    act = "{sb Act: $0-}";
    more = "-- more --";
  };

  # there's two type of statusbars. root statusbars are either at the top
  # of the screen or at the bottom of the screen. window statusbars are at
  # the top/bottom of each split window in screen.
  default = {
    # the "default statusbar" to be displayed at the bottom of the window.
    # contains all the normal items.
    window = {
      disabled = "no";

      # window, root
      type = "window";
      # top, bottom
      placement = "bottom";
      # number
      position = "1";
      # active, inactive, always
      visible = "active";

      # list of items in statusbar in the display order
      items = {
        barstart = { priority = "100"; };
        time = { };
        user = { };
        window = { };
        window_empty = { };
        lag = { priority = "-1"; };
        act = { priority = "10"; };
        more = { priority = "-1"; alignment = "right"; };
        barend = { priority = "100"; alignment = "right"; };
      };
    };

    # statusbar to use in inactive split windows
    window_inact = {
      type = "window";
      placement = "bottom";
      position = "1";
      visible = "inactive";
      items = {
        barstart = { priority = "100"; };
        window = { };
        window_empty = { };
        more = { priority = "-1"; alignment = "right"; };
        barend = { priority = "100"; alignment = "right"; };
      };
    };

    # we treat input line as yet another statusbar :) It's possible to
    # add other items before or after the input line item.
    prompt = {
      type = "root";
      placement = "bottom";
      # we want to be at the bottom always
      position = "100";
      visible = "always";
      items = {
        prompt = { priority = "-1"; };
        prompt_empty = { priority = "-1"; };
        # treated specially, this is the real input line.
        input = { priority = "10"; };
      };
    };

    # topicbar
    topic = {
      type = "root";
      placement = "top";
      position = "1";
      visible = "always";
      items = {
        topicbarstart = { priority = "100"; };
        topic = { };
        topic_empty = { };
        topicbarend = { priority = "100"; alignment = "right"; };
      };
    };
  };
};
settings = {
  core = { real_name = "Unknown"; user_name = "<your_user_name>"; nick = "<your_nick>"; };
  "fe-text" = { actlist_sort = "refnum"; };
};
```

If you're someone who likes to add all sorts of cool functionality, then you should take a look at the [irssi scripts site](http://scripts.irssi.org/) - there are *all sorts* of little gems there.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Awesome answer! Totally working and helped me understand irssi commands better as well!

Comment: @nitstorm You're welcome! Glad to help. :)

Comment: How do you msg? I cant' seem to use the msg command in Irssi :(

Comment: @streetlight I just do "/msg username message", and it opens up a new tab.

Comment: Sorry, yeah that helps. Didn't get a hang of the windows system yet. Thanks!

Comment: Last but not least, enter `/save` to save the config file.

Comment: how do you remove an `autosendcmd`?

Answer (score 6):

If you start `irssi` in Ubuntu, it creates a default configuration file in `~/.irssi/config` already containing your data taken from the system (nickname and *ident* set to your username and realname to your full name).

There is the connection to the [Freenode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freenode) network already set up. Just write `/connect Ubuntu`, `/join #ubuntu`, and repeat for other favorite channels.

You can switch between channels with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>, etc.

You can change nickname with `/nick nitstorm` once connected to the server, or change globally, executing the command `/set nick nitstorm`, and then `/save` to permanently modify your configuration file. The same way, you can change `real_name` and `user_name` with the command `/set`.

You can add autojoin channels with:

```
/channel add -auto #ubuntu Ubuntu
```

(See `/help channel` for help.)

You could also modify the configuration file by hand, but it is better to execute commands to modify it inside irssi, and then save the configuration.

You terminate your session with the command `/quit`.